# How can I create a variable from one value from a query?

Tags: php, mysqli

sorry for the simple question, but I couldn't find an answer:

I have a query with one result row alone, because I use the key column as condition:

```
/* Code für Bestandsabfrage erzeugen */
$sql_bestand = "
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_bestand
    WHERE weinid = $weinid 
    " ;
```

Now I want to use the value of the row "anzahl" in the variable $anzahl:

```
/* Daten einlesen */
$result_bestand = mysql_query($sql_bestand, $conn) or die('Could not insert: ' . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result_bestand);
$anzahl =  $row->anzahl;
```

But this does not work. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are missing a while loop to set your value *during* the fetch operation:

```
$anzahl = null;

mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result_bestand = mysql_query("select * from mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result_bestand)) {
    $anzahl = $row->anzahl;
}

mysql_fetch_object($result_bestand);
```

For more information checkout the first example here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php (English)
- http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-object.php (German)

Comment: Why do I need a while loop when where is only one result row?

Comment: It's because it sets the variable in **PHP** *during* the **SQL** fetch routine. If you do it your way the **SQL** fetch is already completed so there is no value to send to **PHP**. If you try echoing your result outside of the while loop it also won't work. It's because you are dealing with 2 distinct programming languages, **SQL** and **PHP**.

Comment: Or, if you are really stubborn about not using a while loop you can do: `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result_bestand);` then `$anzahl = $row[0]` if anzahl is the first column in the row.. if not replace the 0 with anzahl's index position in the table. i.e. `$anzahl = $row[3]` if it's the 4th column. More info and examples here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-row.php